# High volume blacklist contains operation - performance in C#

Tags: c#, .net, performance

I am working on desktop application which need perform web site access check. I have a huge black lists on PC where application is running, and faced with task:

How to perform fastest check over those black lists?

I'm using C#/.NET development stack, currently my idea load all those lists into hashset and invoke `Contains` method, but I not sure that this is good idea to load it all into memory, maybe you can suggest another way which save memory from one side and will work as fast as it can from another?

The files are in form of plain text, and in the region of megabytes but this size is expected to grow.

**UPDATE**:
I found black lists of web site [here](http://urlblacklist.com/?sec=download) after download and unzip it the size of data about 80 megabytes. So I not sure that keep all data in memory good idea.

**UPDATE 2**

1. I've created perfomance test, downloaded blacklist with 2339643
   items.
2. Loaded it into HashSet and perform 1000 iterations to check
   speed.

### Results:

- The maximum amount of time which `Contains` method take: `0.2
  milliseconds` (this is first call)
- Second call take about '0.0164' milliseconds
  milliseconds and other even less. The perfomance is good.
- But application where I run test take about **250MB** of system memory which
  is not so good as HashSet perfomance.

Comment: Where are you storing your lists?

Comment: How big is your list? MB? GB? TB?

Comment: Faster than working with files would be a simple database with a well-chosen index.

Comment: And the adjective _huge_ is not a good term to understand and size the problem. Better use an approximate number than an adjective

Comment: @Paddy - they will come as plan txt files

Comment: @Kami - megabytes, but they will always grow and I not want keep it in memory because users pc can be not fast as I need

Comment: @vasilyk As you are eliminating the memory storage option you are eliminating any kind of .NET data set options.  You can either query the txt files directly (if the txt files are organised with a decent index) or load the txt files into a database.

Comment: The typical **trade-off** is either it's fast, or it uses little memory - but typically you can't have both. Pick the one that's more important to you ....

Comment: @Steve - I've updated my question with actual size of data. Thanks for you comment.

Comment: @marc_s - yes, I knew, but maybe exists hybrid solution. My blacklists size about 80 MG and will grow. Application not always use functionality for check over this list but when it need it should work, I think less then 200 miliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`HashSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to store your black list, this data structure allows `O(1)` amortised time complexity for inserts and checks if the item is present in the set.

If you need something more scalable, you can consider brining in [redis](http://redis.io/) or [memcached](http://memcached.org/).

Reading through comments, I would consider creating a web service that performs a check. A user can query web service, which in turn would query redis or memchached or slq server if you don't need it all in memory. Alternatively, I would suggest looking at whitelisting, if your black lists grow too much this could indicate a problem with the current approach.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know about HashSet, but it means that I need keep it all in memory always. One note, all this will work on users PC, this is desktop applicatin